# Calling Webservices using Core Java 1.4 api

Tags: java, web-services, java1.4

Is it possible to call a Webservice using core java 1.4 api. Now I have limitation of using java 1.4 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to call web services just using core Java 1.4. You have to use the additional framework like [Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/) to make it work with Java 1.4.